# "Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. No emulator installed. Please download the emulator", for arm image (api 23) in Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android, arm, emulation, haxm, avd-manager

I try to test emulator in Android Studio 3.5
with Armeabi-v7a image, that seems to not require
virtualization (HAXM) but I get such warning, when running
simple android app code for Nexus 6 AVD:

```
"Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
No emulator installed
Please download the emulator".
```

When I click OK I got another error:

```
"All packages are not available for download!
The following packages are not available:
-package id emulator".
```

The version of image is android 6.0 (23) , Marschmallow.
AGP - 3.5, Gradle - 5.4.1.
Sdk Tools 25.2.3, Build Tools 23/25/28,
Platform Tools 23.0.1.
Maybe the version of emulator - API 23 is too old.
I manually unzipped this image to system-image folder from archive in AS temp folder, from previous studio version. But there are just newer Android 24, 25 armeabi-v7a images, another ones is of arm64.
Maybe I need to use cmdline-tools (instead of old sdk tools)
that appeared in 2020, but Android Studio 3.5
in August, 2019.
In case I edit or create new emulator on AVD manager,
when I choose Marschmallow arm image among
other (arm ) images, I see such red info:

```
"No emulator installed
Consider using an x86 system image on an x86 host
for better emulation perfomance".
```

The same text are with another arm images that
I need to download.
Even I install HAXM in SDK Manager the same warning
still remains farther, indeed it is not required for 32-bit system.

When I previously used far old Android Studio 1.4 installed
several years ago on my flash drive, no HAXM required warning
appeared for Android 23 arm image.
Indeed there were error in emulator work or memory  allocation:

```
"This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
emulator: WARNING: userdata partition is resized from 44 M to 0 M
ERROR: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 8
init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!
Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer".

qemu-system-armel.exe glib-error
gmem.c: failed to allocate ... 226491840bytes
```

Indeed I installed AS 3.5 from present installer,
but HAXM required error.
And I do not fully understand what emulator Studio means in this case? As far as I know - it is AVD with image installed on it. I did it. But why it shows no emulator installed? Does it means without HAXM it is not (full) emulator?! And what packages it requires - HAXM or something else. After installing HAXM no changes as well. If I need emulator package, I see no such package in cmdline, neither in Studio, SDK manager.
Once when I searched sites on Android installations, it seems to be viewed that studio 3.5 requires just 64-bit images. I cannot check now, but maybe I need to use older version of AS, even 1.4 one, to just test Android app on my 32-bit Windows 7.  Here https://androiddevelopers.googleblog.com/2019/06/moving-android-studio-and-android.html it is said that Android Studio moves to 64-bit version. That is just before 3.5 version (Project Marble). But I installed AS 3.5 version. Maybe it already did not supported 32-bit emulators? But HAXM anyway requires 64-bit, so if arm-32/64 is not directly correlated with Intel architechture, and requires HAXM it is not possible on 32-bit OS. Can I anybody inform me. I installed AS 3.5 as I have its installer on flash drive, and wasted so much time for it. So maybe I need something more older anyway, something just more newer than AS 1.4 that produced probably memory error on my Pentium 4 32-bit, 2Gb.

Comment: If you have an Intel PC, you probably don't want to use an ARM emulator.  They're *much* slower, because they have to emulate the instruction set of the main PC, instead of using the native one.  I'd take their advice and use the x86 or x86_64 image.  About the only reason to use one of them is if you're writing or testing a C compiler, and don't have access to a real device.

Comment: I have 32-bit processor and 32-bit Windows OS, so I cannot use x86 or x86_64, as there is no virtualization support (HAXM). So I would like to test just ARM image for now,. So my question why Android Studio 3.5 ask HAXM (1.4 did not), maybe it does not support ARMeabi-v7a (32-bit). Maybe 3.5 doesnot support it, because this android-23 image I saved from Android Studio 1.4 (2015). And the only more 32-bit amr image is of android-24,25 version. In download list of arm images android-26 and on is of arm-64 images that my PC does not support.

Comment: My 32-bit processor does not support vt-x on (present on 64-bit ones). It is needed by HAXM for x86 images as well. As I have 32-bit OS. Maybe you can run arm64 images (emulators) in Windows 32, if so, but if it probably also requires HAXM it is not possible too here.

Comment: How old is your machine?  They haven't made 32 bit processors for PCs in a decade.  I highly doubt you could get any of the tools to run on one.  In the very unlikely case you have one, it's time to just get a new computer.